# Properly split a long string to be read by Talkback

Tags: java, android, xml, accessibility, talkback

I have a long string in my android app that looks like this:

```
<string name="imprint_text" translatable="false">
    ...long text here...
</string>
```

The problem is that Talkback is only able to read the whole string from the beginning, indifferent of where on the screen you touch. What is the best way for this to be split into different paragraphs? Should I just create different strings (imprint_text1, imprint_text2...) and bring them in the correct order or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that this is possible. Keep in mind that there's also a limit of 4000 characters if I'm not mistaken. My suggestion would be to use [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#summary). You can start it when the user opens the screen or when they tap on anywhere (probably the first one would be better, but it depends on the app). It has a lot of options for setting the speed and even a playSilence method.

Comment: But at least creating different strings should be possible, no? How would Talkback know that they belong together when there is no grouping or similar?

Comment: You'll either create different strings and group them (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#content-groups), or add everything in one string and handle the speed and the pauses via the TextToSpeech to sound less "robotic"